# When does this code crashes?

Tags: java, windows, file, file-io

This code is from a library that I use and I decompiled because of an error.

On Windows 32 it works correctly if the user that launches the program is an administrator of the machine, otherwise it crashes. On linux it crashes too.

```
/*      */   public static String cambiaEstensione(String nomeFile, String nuovaEstensione)
/*      */   {
/*  140 */     int p = nomeFile.lastIndexOf('.');
/*  141 */     if (p < 0) {
/*  142 */       return nomeFile + "." + nuovaEstensione;
/*      */     }
/*  144 */     return nomeFile.substring(0, p) + "." + nuovaEstensione;
/*      */   }
```

The caller of the function is this:

```
/* 182 */       if (this.fl_scrivi) {
/* 183 */         stato = "Apertura archivio dichiarazioni da inviare...";
/* 184 */         this.dcm = new Dcm();
/* 185 */         this.dcm.setNomeDcm(Util.cambiaEstensione(args[2], "dcm"));
/* 186 */         this.dcm.setFileDcm(new FileOutputStream(this.dcm.getNomeDcm()));
/*     */       }
```

The exception is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .dcm (Accesso negato)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at it.finanze.entrate.sco.main.M77S11.elaboraFile(M77S11.java:186)
```

Where *"Accesso negato"* means *"Access Denied*".

Can you help me to understand the reason of the error?

---

**UPDATE:** The reason of the problem was that I was passing an empty string in `args[2]`.

On Windows with administrator privileges it did not crash because it created the file `C:\.dcm`, not sure if I have to consider that a feature or a bug.

Thank you very much to everybody who answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right there in the stack trace.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .dcm (Accesso negato)
```

It can't find a file named ".dcm" so it seems:

**Either** the calling function passed an empty string for the filename, in other words args[2] returns an empty string at this line

```
this.dcm.setNomeDcm(Util.cambiaEstensione(args[2], "dcm"));
```

**OR** (since this occurs on Linux) args[2] contains a value like ".something" so this line

```
int p = nomeFile.lastIndexOf('.');
```

Returns zero and then this line

```
return nomeFile.substring(0, p) + "." + nuovaEstensione;
```

Returns just empty string + "." + extension. (i.e. ".dcm")

Linux uses ".filename" to denote hidden files

Comment: Grazie mille Paolo! I was just passing an empty string to that parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know Java but it looks like you receive an access denied error ("java.io.FileNotFoundException: .dcm (Accesso negato)").

Are you sure you've the correct access rights?

Comment: Yes, it is a folder on which all the users can read write and execute

Comment: Has the account running your program the correct rights to write in this folder?

Answer (score 1):

The call `this.dcm.getNomeDcm()` returns the string `".dcm"` (for whatever reason) and no file with that name exists. Which is not surprising, since Windows apps don't usually name files with only an extension like that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess "Accesso negato" means that you don't have the permission to open the file. You could try to move the files to another directory, run the programm as administrator, or change the required permissions.

On linux you can check the permissions using `ls -l <file>`
and change them with `chmod 666 <file>` (read and write permission for all)

See also [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Answer (score 1):

```
int p = nomeFile.lastIndexOf('.');
```

If `nomeFile` is the empty string then this will return -1 and the followgin condition is true:

```
 if (p < 0) {
     return nomeFile + "." + nuovaEstensione;
 }
```

This will return the concatentation of an empty string, a dot and the passed in file extension, thus returning ".dmc". A file with this name does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if file really exists and has correct permission.